# How to get a GTM Tag to fire from Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

If I have some javascript fire a jQuery function that gets some data to populate a dataLayer and then push it. What should the trigger look like for the tag?

Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.remove').click(function () {
    // GA to remove item from cart
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
          event: 'ec.remove',
            'ecommerce': {
              'add': {
                'actionField': {'list': 'Course List'},
                'products': [{
                  'id': 1234,
                  'name': 'myThing',
                  'category': 'myCategory',
                  'variant': 'myVariant',
                  'brand': 'theBrand',
                  'quantity': 1,
                  'dimension1': residentialString,
                  'list': 'Course List'
                }]
              }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In GTM I've unsuccessfully tried a Custom Event trigger of name "ec.remove" firing on "Some Custom Events" with conditions of "Click classes - matches CSS selector - a.remove" as well as trying "Click elements .... etc." They don't make sense to me as the event should be triggered by the javascript and not the clicking on a UI element.

Clear end to end documentation that covers the coding AND the GTM set up is sparse if non-existent.

Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Custom events do not have click classes. Using the custom event without filters should work.

Comment: Trigger = Custom event > `ec.remove` on all custom events. Also, change `'add'` to `'remove'` since I understand you want to implement the remove from cart event. Also on the Analytics variable you need to select in "More options" > "Ecommerce" > "Enable ehanced ecommerce features" & "Use dataLayer"

Comment: Thanks both. Removed filters as advised and it now works.  Changed 'add' to 'remove' of course and the Tag was already set up for Enhanced Ecommerce and Use dataLayer.